# Easy way to list IPFS directory contents

Tags: nft, ipfs

I have an image directory that I've posted to IPFS with a large number of images in it. When I try to query the directory using an IPFS HTTP gateway, I get a gateway timeout error as I assume the quantity of files is so high. I am using:

```
https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeiakb6sdfohwdw7dtdbe..../directory
```

Is there a simple way to CURL this directory easily into a json file, or some other method where I can get the file list? I also have IPFS downloaded and installed on my Ubuntu server, but can't figure out how to list the files within this directory through there either...

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking if the cloudflare IPFS gateway works for you to get access to the directory.

Check out [this link here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/distributed-web/ipfs-gateway/#directories).